# Fragment Instantiation Error (...for no good reason)

Tags: android

I'm using the V4 compat lib to use fragments. I have a Fragment that a **top level class with a public, empty constructor**, yet still, every once in a while, my app crashes, with this in the stacktrace:

> android.support.v4.app.Fragment$InstantiationException: Unable to
>   instantiate fragment com.myapp.view.flows.fragment.MyFragment: make
>   sure class name exists, is public, and has an empty constructor that
>   is public

Answer (score 0, accepted):

make sure you call super on the constructor. If you don't need to make any changes to it you better simply not override it.

Comment: Great point. I'm deleting all the empty ones I created where I forgot to call super and had no need for an explicit default one. I'll accept as soon as 9 minutes are up ;)